# One-Many-One Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

A question about whether or not I'm going about something in the best way...

I would like to have a class hierarchy in Python that looks (minimally) like the following;

```
class Actor
  class Mover(Actor)
  class Attacker(Actor)
    class Human(Mover, Attacker)
```

But I run up against the fact that `Actor` has a certain attribute which I'd like to initialise, from each of the `Mover` and `Attacker` subclasses, such as in below;

```
class Actor:
    _world = None
    def __init__(self, world):
        self._world = world

class Mover(Actor):
    _speed = 0
    def __init__(self, world, speed):
        Actor.__init__(self, world)
        self._speed = speed

class Attacker(Actor):
    _range = 0
    def __init__(self, world, range):
        Actor.__init__(self, world)
        self._range = range
```

If I was then to go with my initial approach to this, and follow what I always have in terms of using superclass' constructors, I will obviously end up calling the `Actor` constructor twice - not a *problem*, but my programmer sense tingles and says I'd rather do it a cleaner way;

```
class Human(Mover, Attacker):
    def __init__(self, world, speed, range):
        Mover.__init__(self, world, speed)
        Attacker.__init__(self, world, range)
```

I *could* only call the `Mover` constructor, for example, and simply initialise the `Human`'s `_range` explicitly, but this jumps out at me as a *much* worse approach, since it duplicates the initialisation code for an `Attacker`.

Like I say, I'm aware that setting the `_world` attribute twice is no big deal, but you can imagine that if something more intensive went on in `Actor.__init__`, this situation would be a worry.  Can anybody suggest a better practice for implementing this structure in Python?

Comment: You won't call constructor (better to say 'initializer') twice. That's not how inheritence works. You'd better see MRO topic to clarify Python inheritence for yourself: http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've got here is called [diamond inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). The Python object model solves this via the [method resolution order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) algorithm, which uses [C3 linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization); in practical terms, all you have to do is use `super` and pass through `**kwargs` (and in Python 2, inherit from `object`):

```
class Actor(object):    # in Python 3, class Actor:
    _world = None
    def __init__(self, world):
        self._world = world

class Mover(Actor):
    _speed = 0
    def __init__(self, speed, **kwargs):
        super(Mover, self).__init__(**kwargs)    # in Python 3, super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._speed = speed

class Attacker(Actor):
    _range = 0
    def __init__(self, range, **kwargs):
        super(Attacker, self).__init__(**kwargs) # in Python 3, super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._range = range

class Human(Mover, Attacker):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Human, self).__init__(**kwargs)    # in Python 3, super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Note that you now need to construct `Human` with kwargs style:

```
human = Human(world=world, range=range, speed=speed)
```

What actually happens here?  If you instrument the `__init__` calls you find that (renaming the classes to `A, B, C, D` for conciseness):

- `D.__init__` calls `B.__init__`

  - `B.__init__` calls `C.__init__`

    - `C.__init__` calls `A.__init__`

      - `A.__init__` calls `object.__init__`

What's happening is that `super(B, self)` called on an instance of `D` knows that `C` is next in the method resolution order, so it goes to `C` instead of directly to `A`.  We can check by looking at the MRO:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

For a better understanding, read [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Note that `super` is absolutely not magic; what it does can be approximated in Python itself (here just for the `super(cls, obj)` functionality, using a closure to bypass `__getattribute__` circularity):

```
def super(cls, obj):
    mro = type(obj).__mro__
    parent = mro[mro.index(cls) + 1]
    class proxy(object):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            return getattr(parent, name).__get__(obj)
    return proxy()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  I've always been a little confused as to what, say, `super(self, Human).__init__` refers to in the `Human` initialiser - is this essentially saying 'I'll give all these named arguments to the initialiser of `Human`, and the MRO needs to look upwards and work out which superclass of `Human` can handle those arguments?

Comment: I think if I'd known it was called Diamond Inheritance I might've been able to find some answers on this before posting - I did try, honest! :)

Comment: Ah, useful edits to your answer and everything; if I could upvote more I would, sir.  That clears things up - I've been reading the article posted above by @RostyslavDzinko and am learning about linearization - this is beginning to make sense :)

Comment: @unwitting it's a lot simpler than that; it means "look at the MRO of `self`, walk along it till I find `Human`, and call the method on the class directly after `Human`".